# validating fosuserbundle registration form

Tags: validation, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUserBundle.
In my project, I created my own UserBundle and overrode the controller, the forms and the handlers.
Now when a user tries to register with an existing email, the site crashes (email is unique for doctrine). It seems like there is no validation made.
I thought there would be some validation as I have in my validation.yml:

```
YOP\UserBundle\Entity\User:
  constraints:
    - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: email
  properties:
    email:
      - Email: ~
```

How come the validation isn't made on the email field?
How can I make sure that my validation constraints are taken into account?

PS: the validation.yml file is not in my UserBundle, is that a problem?

EDIT:

the code of my UserBundle is available [here](https://github.com/marronsuisse/yourownpoet/tree/master/src/YOP/UserBundle)
I don't understand why there is no validation done anymore...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved the issue by:

- having the validation.yml file in the same bundle as the one containing my User entity, and pointing to my User Entity
- adding the "Registration" validation group to my fields

validation.yml:

```
YOP\YourOwnPoetBundle\Entity\User:
  constraints:
    - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: email
  properties:
    email:
      - Email: { groups: [Registration] }
    plainPassword:
      - MinLength: { limit: 5, message: "Your password must have at least {{ limit }} characters" }
    name:
      - NotBlank: { groups: [Registration] }
    familyName:
      - NotBlank: { groups: [Registration] }
    sex:
      - Choice: { choices: [1, 2], groups: [Registration] }
    birthdate:
      - NotNull: { groups: [Registration] }
    city:
      - NotBlank: { groups: [Registration] }
    howDidYouHear:
      - Choice: { choices: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], groups: [Registration] }
```

Answer (score -1):

`validation.yml` should be in your user bundle.
`/app/config/config.yml` should be updated as follow:

```
validation:      { enabled: true,  enable_annotations: false }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this doesn't make any difference. How do I tell Symfony2 to use the validation.yml file?