# How to hide fields when override forms in FOSUserBundle

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony

I want to override the edit user form in FOSUserbundle to hide some fields, I created my type extending AbstractType,  I know how to add fields but not how to hide existing ones like username and/or password.
Actually I can hide the username doing

```
$builder->remove('username');
```

how can I hide the password? doing $builder->remove('password'); or $builder->remove('current_password'); doesn't work

thanks

Comment: Some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832916/remove-replace-the-username-field-with-email-using-fosuserbundle-in-symfony2?rq=1

Comment: yeah I know that but how can I hide the password field?

Comment: @user3174311, your issue is quite basic and solution should be simple too :) if you really think you should extend your form take a look into http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html, but i dont think its necessary. meanwhile I will delete my answer and vote your question up so it would get more attention

Comment: @user3174311 p.s. once again I propose you to rely on form customization recipe from symfony cookbook http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html