# Skip validation if sibling (checkbox) field contains 'false'

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form containing a checkbox and a "value field". The value field could be anything, a text box, a compound field, a collection - anything.

The form could look like this, for example:

```
field_1_label    enabled    [x]
                 value      [________]

field_2_label    enabled    [x]
                 value      sub_field_1    [________]
                            sub_field_2    [________]

field_3_label    enabled    [x]
                 value      [________]
```

When the "enabled" field contains `true`, everything works fine already. When the "enabled" field contains `false`, I would like to **disable validation on the value field and it's child fields**.

So when "enabled" is un-checked, I will effectively ignore the field. I will still display it in the form, but I won't store the data and I certainly don't want it validated.

Does anybody have suggestions for how I might do this? Specifically, I'm having problems getting the validation system to ignore the value field *and* any potential child fields.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Symfony 2.3 you can use false in validation_groups to have no constraints applied:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/button_based_validation.html

So for example, on the field containing the checkbox and value field:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver
        ->setDefaults([
            'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form) {
                // If the form is disabled, don't use any constraints
                if ($form->get('enabled_checkbox')->getData() == false) {
                    return false;
                }
                
                // Otherwise, use the default validation group
                return 'Default';
            }
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Does this still work for 2.4? I'm having trouble with it; returning `false` does not appear to disable validation for the form.

Comment: Ok, I was able to get it to work by instead returning an empty array, instead of `false`

Comment: Still a very useful trick in 2023 on Symfony 6.4

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the child fields prior to validation if the parent's checkbox is set to false.

Read more in the cookbook article [How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).

Subscribe to [form events](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Form/FormEvents.html) `FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA` and remove the field in your subscriber.

The section [Adding an Event Subscriber to a Fom class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-subscriber-to-a-form-class) covers this topic.

---

You can aswell introduce different [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups) for your form.

Just apply another validation group ( not containing the chield fields ) if the parent's checkbox is set to false.

Comment: The issue with removing them is that the fields will be unavailable when the form is redisplayed - there'll be an 'enabled' checkbox but no value field if there are validation errors elsewhere on the form. It kind of leaves the form in a broken state, unless I add the fields back after validation.

Although from SUBMIT / POST_SUBMIT onwards it's no longer possible to remove (or add) fields since the call to ->setParent(null) on the child will throw the exception 'You cannot remove children from a submitted form'.

Comment: using POST_SET_DATA instead of POST_BIND does not help ? i added another possibility in the answer - just use validation groups. please review.

Comment: Validation happens POST_BIND so if I was going to skip the fields by removing pre-validation, I would need to add them again on POST_BIND, which isn't possible. Regarding validation groups, it seems it could be useful, but I don't see how I could specify the groups to validate? If I build various validation groups, it looks to me like the form system is hard-coded to only ever validate the "Default" group? (line 55 of Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\EventListener\ValidationListener)

Comment: just don't introduce any asserts using the default group  and change the one's used by your form prior to validating.

Comment: you can set validation groups on your form dynamically and provide defaults with the validation_groups option -> see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8820022/1832745