# Symfony2: Form validation between entities

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I've got form containing 2 entities:

```
-A
-B
```

Entity `A` got field `country`. Entity B got special special field let's call it `x`. 
I want to do a conditional validation. If field `country` in `A` entity got specific value then `x` field from entity `B` should be validated else validation should be skipped.

```
 <class name="A">

        <property name="country">
            <constraint name="Country>
                <option name="message">pso.country.incorrect</option>
            </constraint>
        </property>

    </class>


  <class name="B">

    <property name="x">
        <constraint name="X">
            <option name="message">pso.x.incorrect</option>
        </constraint>
    </property>

</class>
```

Is it possible to pass result of `A-class` `country` field validator to `B-class` `x` field validator?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can read this [part](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#groups-based-on-the-submitted-data) of the documentation :)

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to do sth like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104501/skip-validation-if-sibling-checkbox-field-contains-false  the second answer but it is not working correctly.

Comment: It is based on fos_user_bundle. In config.yml I've got             validation_groups: [ Default, Registration, PlatformRegistration ] and In for setDefault validation_groups I'm trying to do sth from the link above.