# symfony2: How to add validation rules to username?

Tags: symfony, validation, fosuserbundle

Since I am extending the `BaseUser`, I don't have the property `$name` in my user entity. How can I add validation to it? Can I just add a property `$username` to this entity? Would that mess with or override certain functionality or validation or such that is provided natively to a user class?

I rad this question: [FOSUserBundle - Validation for username, password or email fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702353/fosuserbundle-change-username-validation).
But since I am using a bunch of annotation validations, that won't work for me.

Follow-up question - I see that in `fosUSerBundle` XML file, for validating the user that it has natively a checker for use of a taken username. I don't get that functionality, mine goes straight to a SQL error message if I try to add a user with the same name as an existing user. Is this somehow because I am using annotations which overrides the XML validation file all together?

```
<?php
namespace BizTV\UserBundle\Entity;

use BizTV\UserBundle\Validator\Constraints as BizTVAssert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company as company;


class User extends BaseUser implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;  

//TODO: Add regex on $name for a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _ (underscore) 
//TODO: Add constraint on $name    * @BizTVAssert\NameExists    (and finish coding this constraint)

    /**
    * @var object BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company
    *  
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    */
    protected $company; 

    /**
    * @var object BizTV\UserBundle\Entity\UserGroup
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BizTV\UserBundle\Entity\UserGroup")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userGroup", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
    */
    protected $userGroup;
```

So I have looked here ([symfony2 using validation groups in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322441/symfony2-using-validation-groups-in-form)) and tried that solution by adding this to the controller when building the form. Nothing happens (still jumps straight to the INSERT INTO SQL error)

```
    $entity  = new User();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm(new newUserType($tempCompany), $entity, array('validation_groups'=>'registration'));
    $form->bind($request);
```

I have also tried to set this validation group "registration group" (that is supposed to give you unique user & email validation "for free") this way, in the form class:

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'validation_groups' => array('registration'),
));
}
```

Still nothing happens. Straight to the SQL error upon save.

Answer (score 3):

I apologize ahead of time. I'm not entirely sure if you want to validate a `$name` property or the `$username` property, but I hope this points you in the right direction.

To add a `$name` property with the regex validation, it should look something like this. Not tested, but this is where I would start:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"Registration","Profile"})
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/", groups={"Registration","Profile"})
     */
    protected $name;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

The unique usernameCanonical and emailCanonical validations are inherited, but they are in validation groups. More information about validation groups [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#book-validation-validation-groups) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-forms-validation-groups).

It seems to me so far that the FOSUserBundle uses the user manager like a repository of sorts, so you will want to use that to interact with the storage layer as much as possible. Here is what that might look like in a controller (again, not tested):

```
// setting values manually
$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->createUser();
$user->setName('Joe');
$user->setUsername('joeuser');
$user->setEmail('joe@gmail.com');
$user->setPlainPassword('secret');
$user->addRole('ROLE_EDITOR');

// persist to database
$userManager->updateUser($user);

// inherited validations that check for username and email uniqueness
// using validation group names 'Registration' and 'Profile'
$uniqueEmail = $user->getEmailCanonical();
$uniqueUsername = $user->getUsernameCanonical();
```

If you are using a form builder, or a form type that is not provided by the bundle, it could look something like this:

```
// setting values from a form
$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->createUser();

$form = $this->container->get('form.factory')
    ->createBuilder('form', $user, array('validation_groups' => 'Registration'))
    ->add('username', 'text')
    ->add('email', 'email')
    ->add('name', 'text')
    ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
        'type' => 'password'
    ))
    ->getForm();

if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        // redirect response
    }
}

return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse($templateName, array(
    'form' => $form->createView()
));
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if I can provide more detail. I would post some of my code here, but my implementation is a bit different.

Comment: Now I'm looking at validating the username (althoug a regexp for something else is interesting as well. Is my own answer (which isn't really an answer) to this question shows, I did a little workaround for that. But I can't inherit this said to be "free" functionality of unique username and emai...

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/validation/orm.xml) is the ORM User validation. You will see the `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity` are set for validation groups 'Registration' and 'Profile', so 'registration' will not work.

Comment: Try `$userManager->updateUser($entity, false); var_dump($entity); exit();` to see what your entity values are. I'm not sure what else to try, since you have a lot of different code trying to do the same thing (like the validator event listeners in your form). I typically solve these kinds of problems by looking at the data in the object to make sure everything is set correctly. Specifically, usernameCanonical, emailCanonical, plainPassword, password, etc...

Comment: I suspect the usernameCanonical field is not set. Try calling `$userManager->updateCanonicalFields($entity);` **before** your validations. I wanted to find out if the usernameCanonical field was set (otherwise the validation will not work). If you call updateCanonicalFields manually, then validate, I bet it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to combine constraints defined in both annotations and in PHP (but probably not both those defined in annotations and XML)

```
<?php

/* ... */

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

class User extends BaseUser implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
  /* ... */

  public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
  {
    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint(
        'username'
      , new Assert\Regex(array(
            'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]$/'
        )
    ));
    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint(
        'username'
      , new BizTVAssert\NameExists()
    ));
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly an answer to the question, but a solution for me so far. I added the validator to my form (UserType).

```
    $validatorUsername = function(FormEvent $event){
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $myExtraField = $form->get('username')->getData();
        if ( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/',$myExtraField) == false ) {
          $form['username']->addError(new FormError("Du får inte använda andra specialtecken än understreck (_)"));
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the callback validation constraint which is documented in the Symfony cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

Example:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company;

/**
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"validateName"})
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;  

/**
* @var object BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company
*  
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
*/
protected $company; 

/**
* @var object BizTV\UserBundle\Entity\UserGroup
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BizTV\UserBundle\Entity\UserGroup")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userGroup", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
*/
protected $userGroup;   

/**
 * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
 */
public function validateName(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    // do some validation

    // or add violation
        $context->addViolationAt(
            'name',
            'Name "%name% is not valid',
            array('%name%' => $this->getName()),
            null
        );
}
```

Comment: Nut to check for other users with same name requires a database connection, I was under the impression such queries can't (or at least shouldn't) be run from within the entity class?

Comment: In Symfony 2.4 you can set these callback validation in external classes. See the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/Callback.html

Comment: Ah, misunderstood you. Maybe this is what you searching for?
http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/custom-validation-property-path#creating-a-proper-custom-validation-constraint
I don't know a better solution for it

Answer (score 0):

For changing the validation on `$username`, I encourage you to do take the steps describe in [FOSUserBundle - Change username validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16704124/1237411), it's the easiest way. There's nothing wrong with using both XML and Annotations in a single project. It's actually recommended to *not* use Annotations, as it keeps the mapping metadata outside of the entities/classes, which is the whole point of the ([Data](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)) [Mapper pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/mapper.html).

Another way to go is to *not* extend `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`, but implement `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface`. There's a small adjustment you'll have to make to `UserProvider` and `UserManager` to make this work, it's described [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1172#issuecomment-20007203).
Next you'll have to do all the mapping yourself, for which you can freely use any Annotations you want.

As for validating the uniqueness of `$username` you should note 2 things:

1. You're not checking if a property is unique, but if the entity is unique (based on a property). So the validator is not placed on a property, but on an entity.
2. FOSUserBundle translates the `$username` to `$usernameCanonical`, and validates if the `User` entity is unique based on `$usernameCanonical`. This is actually very nice system, because you can influence the value that is used in the uniqueness check. You can even go further than `strtolower` (the default), like remove non-word characters, change é to e, etc. So don't really see any value in checking `$username` itself for uniqueness.